# How to add 2 numbers together that are of different lengths in x86 linux nasm assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, bigint

I'm very new to assembly and having difficulties in getting basic calculations to work with different length numbers.

So this is my adding code, that works with numbers that are 3 or less characters long. for as long as both are the same length. for example 123 + 123 works just fine and outputs 246. But 12 + 123 does not work and it outputs 253 as the answer.
How would I be able to get this working with different length numbers?

```
    sys_exit equ 1
    sys_read equ 3
    sys_write equ 4
    stdin equ 0
    stdout equ 1

    section .data
        newLine db 10
        cquestion db 'Enter a number: ', 0xa
        cqLen equ $ - cquestion

        answer db 'Your answer is: '
        aLen equ $ - answer


    section .bss

        number1 resb 4
        number2 resb 4
        number1Len resd 1
        number2Len resd 1

        answ resb 8

    %macro write_string 2
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, %1
        mov edx, %2
        int 0x80
    %endmacro

    section .text
    global _start
    _start:
    write_string cquestion, cqLen

    mov eax, sys_read
    mov ebx, stdin
    mov ecx, number1
    mov edx, 4
    int 0x80
    mov [number1Len], eax

    write_string cquestion, cqLen

    mov eax, sys_read
    mov ebx, stdin
    mov ecx, number2
    mov edx, 4
    int 0x80
    mov [number2Len], eax

    write_string answer, aLen

    clc
    mov ecx, [number2Len]           ;number of digits
    dec ecx                         ;need to decrease one for some reason?
    mov esi, ecx                
    dec esi                         ;pointing to the rightmost digit.
    .add_loop:

        mov al, [number1 + esi]
        adc al, [number2 + esi]
        aaa
        pushf               ; also no idea what this is here for
        or  al, 30h         ; or this
        popf                ; and this...

        mov [answ + esi], al
        dec esi
        loop addition.add_loop

        mov eax, sys_write
        mov ebx, stdout
        mov ecx, answ
        mov edx, 8
        int 0x80
        
        mov eax, sys_write
        mov ebx, stdout
        mov ecx, newLine
        mov edx, 1
        int 0x80

    mov [answ], DWORD 0
```

Comment: "need to decrease one for some reason?" - to get rid of the newline at the end. The `pushf`/`popf` is to preserve the value of the carry flag for the next iteration. The `or al, 30h` is converting to text by adding the ascii code of `0`. To handle differing lengths just pretend the shorter one is padded with zeroes.

Comment: Doing 1 digit at a time is pretty inefficient.  Especially using `pushf`/`or`/`popf` instead of `lea eax, [eax + 0x30]` if that that `0x30` bit is always unset to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your loop never does more than 3 iterations. If there's a final carry, you'll need an extra write to the destination.
- If the code needs to deal with different length inputs, then you can't use the same offset `ESI` to address corresponding digits from both numbers.
- And neither can you use that same `ESI` to store the output since you could need one extra position to the left.
- About `answ resb 8`, summing a couple of 3-digit numbers can at most produce a 4-digit sum.

**Below is one of the many solutions to this question**.

```
                           ECX=1
                           v
num1:  31 32 0A 00      31 32 30 30
num2:  31 32 33 0A      31 32 33 30
                              ^
                              EDX=2

answ:                   00 00 00 00     --> 30 31 33 35
                                 ^
                                 EDI=3
```

```
    mov   ecx, [number1Len]           ; Number of bytes (eg. 3)
    sub   ecx, 2                      ; Offset to 'ones' digit
    lea   eax, [ecx + 1]              ; Offset to the newline
  .more1:
    mov   byte [number1 + eax], 30h
    inc   eax
    test  eax, 3
    jnz   .more1

    mov   edx, [number2Len]           ; Number of bytes (eg. 4)
    sub   edx, 2                      ; Offset to 'ones' digit
    lea   eax, [edx + 1]              ; Offset to the newline
  .more2:
    mov   byte [number2 + eax], 30h
    inc   eax
    test  eax, 3
    jnz   .more2

    mov   edi, 3                      ; 4 iterations
    clc
  .add_loop:
    movzx eax, byte [number1 + ecx]
    adc   al, [number2 + edx]
    aaa
    lahf                              ; Preserves CF gotten from `aaa`
    or    al, 30h                     ; Convert into character "0" to "9"
    mov   [answ + edi], al
    dec   ecx
    and   ecx, 3                      ; Wraparound in number1
    dec   edx
    and   edx, 3                      ; Wraparound in number2
    sahf                              ; Restores CF
    dec   edi
    jns   .add_loop
```

In the result in *answ* we can remove at most 3 leading zeroes. If the true result is 0, the 4th character in *answ* would have to remain.

```
    mov   edx, 4
    mov   ecx, answ
  .del:
    cmp   byte [ecx], 30h
    jne   .ok
    dec   edx
    inc   ecx
    cmp   edx, 1
    ja    .del
  .ok:
    mov   ebx, stdout
    mov   eax, sys_write
    int   80h
```

Comment: Note that saving/restoring CF can be done significantly more cheaply with sahf / lahf.  Or even `setc al` / `add al, 255`.  Also, if the BigInt used little-endian order (least-significant chunk at lowest address) like normal, you *could* use the same offset into each static array.  When you get to the end of one, then you're *just* doing carry propagation through the rest of the other (`movzx` / `adc al, 0` / `aaa` or something to propagate AF to CF since this is unpacked BCD?), and can optionally fall back to just copying once carry isn't propagating.

Comment: @SepRoland
Are you sure that is correct? It is not working for me. And what I noticed is that just before .more2: you do 'mov eax, ecx', which would move the offset of number1Len into eax when we actually would like to move the offset of number2Len into eax, which is in edx as far as I can understand. But even after changing that the code is not working properly.

Also I agree that prepended zero's in the answer is not the prettiest thing, so could we just add a 'hardcoded' zero into the code that we would add into the longer number instead of a prepended zero?

Comment: @Lauri Me using `ECX` where it needed to be `EDX`  is the perfect example of copy/paste going wrong! Nonetheless, I made too many errors in this answer. The preparatory loops ran for too long and I didn't acknowledge the fact that this was about unpacked BCD. I believe my edit today has it right this time (fingers crossed). I have added code to remove redundant leading zeroes.

Comment: @SepRoland yeah, now it's working beautifully. FYI your mistakes made me take a good look at the code you wrote and while it took me many hours I started to see the same mistakes that you listed, would have taken me ages to get that working as you have. So thanks for the answer, and the learning opportunity!

Comment: @Lauri Thanks for your kind words, and happy learning.